# Должен ли сайт так растягиваться после ширины 1920px?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Если так не должно быть, то напишите как должно и как решить.

[Сайт](https://roderen.github.io/teleport/)

[репозиторий](https://github.com/Roderen/teleport)

[На всякий случай сам макет](https://www.figma.com/file/8I9rwZPlqOSX5swxrHHHIk/Teleport-(Copy)?node-id=79%3A1201)

Может контейнер для всего контента сделать?

В макете главная страница 1779px (как это делали), но не суть. Если отдалить (ctrl+scroll или код элемента) больше чем на 1920px, то контент как по мне не будет хорошо смотреться на 2500 и больше. Или это норма, что он так растягивается?
Ps. На адаптив не обращайте внимание!

Comment: ничего непонятно

Comment: @Grundy В каком смысле?

Comment: В прямом: непонятно о чем вопрос, непонятно какое поведение сейчас, непонятно какое поведение должно быть, непонятно, почему не устраивает текущее поведение

Comment: @Grundy Ну смотри...
На экранах до 2500px +- смотрится ещё более менее, а вот уже если больше (к примеру 4000пх), то как по мне не должно такого быть, разве нет?
Вот как выглядит на 1920 - https://imgur.com/a/0ihQesU
Вот как на 4000 - https://imgur.com/a/e8LbhjH

Comment: @Grundy на 3000-4000пх весь контент разъезжается и смотрится не особо. Разве он должен так разъезжаться?

Comment: @Grundy на 4000px половина сайтов отображается криво. С экраном 4к при работе без масштабирования работа с браузером возможна только открытым на пол экрана.

Comment: @markus у вас на макете растровое изображение. Растягивать имеет смысл, когда изображение векторное.  На вашем месте, я бы не верстал макет магнитом к правой части. На мой взгляд, лучше оставить посередине.

Comment: @markus, что значит "смотрится ещё более менее"? Чего именно _не должно такого быть_? Добавь картинки с примерами непосредственно в вопрос, чтобы сразу было видно что не так

Comment: @DiD, _"отображается криво"_ - это субъективное понятие

Comment: @Grundy согласен. И тем не менее, работа с 4к предусматривает масштабирование средствами системы. И в таком случае, хоть экран и 4к. В браузере будет определяться через JS, например при масштабе 2х, 1920х1080. И `@media`-запросы будут работать как для FHD.

Comment: @Grundy будет ли разумно сделать так как я сделал в этом коммите? - https://roderen.github.io/teleport/
То есть при отдалении экрана, от 1920px весь контент центрируется и по идеи на больших экранах всё должно отображаться нормально.
Как видно тут - https://github.com/Roderen/teleport/commit/23da36f82f3c45ba57e3b78957c2df757d01ff85 я обернул весь контент в отдельный блок (.container) и задал ему:
max-width: 1920px; margin: 0 auto;
Разумно ли это?)

Comment: @markus, что значит _при отдалении экрана_?

Comment: @Grundy Ну что тут непонятного? В моём случае "отдаление", иными словами при большем экране чем 1920... По другому немного скажу: разумно ли будет сделать так - imgur.com/a/wBY0bM5 вместо такого - imgur.com/a/lywc6n7

Comment: @markus, и так и так выглядит не очень

Comment: @Grundy А как по другому? Просто если взять тот же kanobu или тот же stack overflow, то там так же)

Comment: @markus, но это не значит, что это хорошее решение :-) у меня нет телевизора в 4k, чтобы проверить, как это выглядит на реальном устройстве ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy ну это да) Просто смотрю (с помощью такого же способа) в 4000 на том же хабре или канобу и точно такая же штука как у меня.

Answer (score 3):

Однозначного ответа на этот вопрос быть не может.

Приведу примеры на собственном опыте, как это может работать в реальности:

1. У меня телевизор 4K диагональю 49 дюймов. Я его использую
   как монитор, сижу вплотную к нему.
   У меня стоит программа "MaxTo", которая не позволяет окнам
   расширяться больше заданной области в середине. Для программ выходит примерно то
   же самое что обычный небольшой монитор. Ваш сайт при таком варианте будет как на любом обычном мониторе, а вокруг браузера будет ещё продолжаться экран телевизора.
2. Этот же телевизор может сам открывать сайты без ПК. И тогда его
   разрешение становится 1920, то есть пиксели становятся крупными.
   Видимо рассчитано на то, что люди должны находиться далеко от него,
   и мелкие пиксели при этом только зря нагрузят процессор и прочие
   детали.
3. Я мог не ставить никакие программы и открывать окна на
   весь телевизор. Тогда разрешение будет 4K и буду сидеть
   вплотную и видеть огромные окна. Но тексты и менюшки будут как на обычном
   мониторе (не крупные).
4. Или вы можете в этом случае сделать увеличение масштабов вёрстки, например перевести все числа в CSS на vw после разрешения 1920. Тогда издалека это будет идеально - полная чёткость и размеры контролов хорошие. Но вблизи, как пользуюсь я, будет всё огромное.
5. Я могу делать то же самое, что в пункте 3, но отойти на
   три метра, и потом жаловаться, что вы сделали всё мелко.
6. Можно купить монитор 4K с малой диагональю как обычный монитор. Но из вёрстки
   нельзя определить какая диагональ. Остаётся гадать, телевизор это
   или нет.
7. На крупном экране может быть установлено какое угодно разрешение. Часто у людей стоят какие-то жуткие разрешения, прямоугольные пиксели плывут и так далее.
8. Есть мониторы, большие по ширине, но обычные по высоте. На них сайт должен оставаться центрированным, с разрешением как на 1920. Можно конечно проверять медиазапросом в CSS малую высоту экрана по отношению к ширине, и делать какие-то исключения тогда, но это лишний уровень сложности.

Раньше у нас был приблизительный ориентир соответствия размера пикселей и дюймов экрана, а сейчас его нет. Также мы не знаем, что предпочитает пользователь и на каком расстоянии он находится. Я бы не заморачивался с масштабами и просто центрировал сайт, оставив всё как на 1920. Кому не нравится, может накрутить масштаб в браузере или в операционной системе. Этот и любые другие варианты будут иметь недостатки. Или спросите у заказчика и сделайте как он сказал, на удобном ему расстоянии от экрана и всё в таком духе.